# Почему нет перехода на роут в Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

У меня не отрабатывает переход на роут.
Странно то, что в других местах работает, а в этом месте нет.
В списке зарегистрированных роутов данные роут есть,
при этом переход на данный роут идёт с совершенного другого роута, но перехода нет.

```
this.router.navigate(['/category']);
```

Подскажите, с чем может быть это связано?
Я пробовал и с NavigetbyUrl тоже. Остаётся разьве полный релоад делать, но я так не хочу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это переход относительно текущего адреса?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin , да. из /oldroute to /suppliers . на одном и том же сервере локалхосте и порту

Comment: То есть должно получиться /oldroute/suppliers (тогда надо добавить relativeTo), или вместо /oldroute должно стать /suppliers, тогда надо смотреть как прописаны руты в объявлении

Comment: @Alexander Chernin  переход из localhost/oldurl   to   localhost/supplies  .Ноя столкнулся с тем, что часть ссылок работает, а эта нет. Я перезапускал - думал...может кеш

Comment: Надо смотреть объявление с учетом вот этого https://angular.io/guide/router#route-order

Comment: Нужно больше кода, возможно у вас ленивые модули, у которых забыли импортировать route-модули. В целом - причин много, добавьте модуль для `/suppliers`, роут-модуль, который описывает этот путь, чтобы было понятнее, в чем может быть проблема

Comment: @Sergey Glazirin обновил с картинкой. В основном модуле лейзи лоадинг, а потом по компонентам в другом модуле

Comment: @RakzinRoman лучше код добавлять не картинкой, а тексом. Так будет легче с ним работать. Также посмотрите, импорттироли ли catalog-route.module в catalog.module - возможно проблема тут. Также посмотрите ошибки в консоли, возможно там какая-то ошибка есть